# How can I allow remote access to my VM

Tags: virtualbox

Suppose I set up a CentOS machine with the familiar LAMP stack, and I assign (using `eth1`) a dynamic IP to it via DCHP, how can I enable someone from outside my network to view the virtual machine on port 80.

Using my phone (not the host machine), I can currently see the VM on port 80 (just a simple webpage) by going to the IP `192.168.1.100`, so internally my setup works with `eth1` using DCHP.

Hopefully this explains my requirements betters
[image]

Comment: How is your VM connected to your host's network (my network) and what do you mean by "outside my network". What's the thing separating inside from outside?

Comment: With a bridged connection on device `eth1`. Something outside my network, say a friend on the internet. I guess the overall question is "How can I use a VM as a public web server"

Comment: You need to assign a fixed IP address to the VM within your intranet, then forward port 80 to that IP within your router settings.

Comment: A bridged connection means your VM is logically on the same network as the host machine so you just need port mapping as @AFH suggested.

Comment: @billc.cn - It is important to assign a _fixed_ IP, as otherwise forwarding will fail whenever the VM's IP changes.

Comment: Ah thanks! I'll give it a go when I'm home on my network. If any of you want to provide an answer with the details discussed in the comments, I'll accept it later